# spring with testNG without subclassing

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, testng

is there any way to use testNG and spring without subclassing or copying half of `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`? is there anything simple like junit's `@RunWith`?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework), it doesn't look like it provides a TestNG test runner out of the box:

> In addition to generic testing infrastructure, the TestContext framework provides explicit support for JUnit 3.8.2, JUnit 4.5+, and TestNG 5.10 in the form of abstract support classes. For JUnit 4.5+, the framework also provides a custom Runner that allows one to write test classes that are not required to extend a particular class hierarchy.

I suppose you could try to write a your own custom TestNG test runner that could do something similar.